# Finding Max Value a Time Series data in R Programming

Tags: r

I have data as

```
cmpny_name Hr_Min_Sec   Price   Hr_min
A         09:15:41   7610    09:15
A         09:15:42   7632    09:15
A         09:15:43   7654    09:15
A         09:16:21   7655    09:16
A         09:16:59   7854    09:16
A         09:17:32   7453    09:17
A         09:17:42   7467    09:17
A         09:17:58   7557    09:17
A         09:18:03   7567    09:18
A         09:18:58   7659    09:18
A         09:18:59   7810    09:18
```

Here, I want find the the max(Hr_Min_Sec) in every Hr_min and have to display the result as

```
cmpny_name Hr_Min_Sec   Price   Hr_min
A         09:15:43   7654    09:15
A         09:16:59   7854    09:16
A         09:17:58   7557    09:17
A         09:18:59   7810    09:18
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` to present your data! Edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43208434/edit

Comment: Author made comments to both answers about sqldf package.  This is not mentioned anywhere in the question.  The question needs editing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")

dt <- fread(
  'cmpny_name Hr_Min_Sec   Price   Hr_min
A         09:15:41   7610    09:15
A         09:15:42   7632    09:15
A         09:15:43   7654    09:15
A         09:16:21   7655    09:16
A         09:16:59   7854    09:16
A         09:17:32   7453    09:17
A         09:17:42   7467    09:17
A         09:17:58   7557    09:17
A         09:18:03   7567    09:18
A         09:18:58   7659    09:18
A         09:18:59   7810    09:18')
dt[, .SD[max(Hr_Min_Sec)==Hr_Min_Sec,], by=Hr_min] # or
dt[, .SD[.N], by=Hr_min] # the last row in the group  
#    Hr_min cmpny_name Hr_Min_Sec Price
# 1:  09:15          A   09:15:43  7654
# 2:  09:16          A   09:16:59  7854
# 3:  09:17          A   09:17:58  7557
# 4:  09:18          A   09:18:59  7810
```

Comment: Thanks Jogo . . But I tried this . . I couldn't get the result. I've a doubt. Can we use max() function with where statement with sqldf package? If yes, Can you explain for my data?

Comment: I Tried this code,  closingprice_df <- sqldf("select price,Hr_Min_Sec,Hr_Min from df1 where Hr_Min_Sec==max(Hr_Min_Sec)")      But I got the following error,    Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  misuse of aggregate function max()

Comment: I edited my answer. I suppose a solution with sqldf is possible. In your SQL-part you have no "GROUP BY ...".

Answer (score 0):

```
df1[!duplicated(df1$Hr_min, fromLast = TRUE), ]

   cmpny_name Hr_Min_Sec Price Hr_min
3           A    9:15:43  7654   9:15
5           A    9:16:59  7854   9:16
8           A    9:17:58  7557   9:17
11          A    9:18:59  7810   9:18
```

modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23461294/3242130

Comment: Thanks Mano. But unfortunately I couldn't bring the expected output using this code. Can you help me with the usage of sql where statement for this data by using the sqldf package?     I Tried this code,  closingprice_df <- sqldf("select price,Hr_Min_Sec,Hr_Min from df1 where Hr_Min_Sec==max(Hr_Min_Sec)")      But I got the following error,    Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  misuse of aggregate function max()

Comment: Why not use the query to pull all the data into a data.frame and then modify the data.frame?  Sure it's two steps, but it's likely simpler to develop and troubleshoot.